# Xcode new project with same folder name erased my folder

Tags: xcode, macos

Xcode new project with same folder name erased my folder how to get that folder back

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. When new project creates at existing folder Xcode shows dialog:

> A file or folder with the same name already exists in the folder
>   %your_folder%. Replacing it will overwrite its current contents.

The last chance is if you've used `git` and saved it remote you can simply pull it back. Or if you have a backup, you can return deleted files back. Check out your last backup by using Time Machine option in System Preferences on your Mac.